Issue with nasapower R library
Can anyone help me to fix this error message from the R's nasapower library?

Error in post_process_plurals(pstr, values): Cannot pluralize without a quantity

# precipitation corrected sum (PRECTOTCORR_SUM)
library(nasapower)
clima <- get_power(community = "ag",
                   lonlat = c(47.68, 19.93),
                   pars = c("PRECTOTCORR_SUM"),
                   dates = c("2014-01-01", "2015-12-31"),
                   temporal_api = "daily")
clima
head(clima, 5)


The value of "PRECTOTCORR_SUM" is not valid. Where did you see that listed? If you use "PRECTOTCORR" the code runs without error. The error message you see is actually coming from the formatting of the error message it's trying to show you.

I get it from this page: https://gist.github.com/abelcallejo/d68e70f43ffa1c8c9f6b5e93010704b8#meteorology

"PRECTOTCORR" and "PRECTOTCORR_SUM" are two distinct variables

That variable isn't available in the daily ag report. You can see where it is available with purrr::imap(nasapower:::parameters, function(x, n) any(x=="PRECTOTCORR_SUM")). Valid parameter values are pulled from https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/pages/?urls.primaryName=Manager

Looking at the NASA POWER documentation (https://power.larc.nasa.gov/) this variable is not available on the hourly or daily scales, only the PRECTOTCORR variable. I believe that's it. Good job!
